# construct span from a map

Tags: c++, llvm-clang, c++20

I have a map which I wish to return a span over, like the below

```
map<string, map<string, Struct>> map;
span<pair<string, map<string, Struct>>> s {map.begin(), map.end()};
```

Which fails to compile complaining that there is no known conversion from the map::iterator to the span templated type. I'm not sure why this is failing, as from what I understand the iterator range constructor should decompose the map iterator (into pair>) and then 'copy' that over. What am I missing here?

Compiled with clang8

Answer (score 5):

`std::span` can be used only over a collection of contiguous and congruent elements in memory, which `std::map` is not.

[`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)

> The class template span describes an object that can refer to a
>   contiguous sequence of objects with the first element of the sequence
>   at position zero.
>
> A typical implementation holds only two members: a pointer to T and a
>   size.

Comment: I see, I assumed the iterator pair would just walk the range and store each address in the span

Comment: @Madden: And where would the memory for that array of pointers come from? `span` doesn't allocate memory; it's a view type.

Answer (score -1):

C++20 offers ranges, which will work with a map.

However, you might want to rethink why you are actually doing this. The main point of `std::span` is to provide a C++ container interface for a raw memory block. A map already provides a C++ container interface.

Comment: The main point here is that `std::span` is used for continuous elements while `std::map` is node-based container.

Comment: @JohnDing Which is exactly why std::range will work, since they don't require a continuous memory block.